# "Redirect URI doesnot match registered redirect URI" in instagram integration in IOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, instagram

I am working on iPad app, and I need to integrate Instagram. I found a sample that works fine. But coming to my app I registered as new user in instagram developer account. Though I am following the steps as said in Instagram API docs, I am getting an error "Redirect URI doesnot match registered redirect URI".

Can someone guide me on how to generate Redirect URI?

Here is what I did in Instagram.[image]

And in my simulator I am getting this error :

[image]

Comment: Probably you mistyped your redirect URL or "/" may have an impact, be careful with special symbols as well as spaces in strings.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use REDIRECT URI : igeb6240d263fb4736b3740af87edd18ea://authorize
for your Application

your REDIRECT URI should be : "ig" + "your clientId" + "://authorize"

Comment: This doesn't work because I cannot input non-http/https redirect_uri in Instagram developer portal, and Instagram denies any unregistered redirect_uris.

Comment: @Sujal This url is not acceptable on the developer portal.( "ig" + "your clientId" + "://authorize")     What exact url we need to add on Dev portal of Instagram

Comment: @Sujal Instagram client register portal doesn't accept non http(s) protocol. We can't enter myapp://authorize. I have tried to enable implicit mode by uncheck the Disable implicit OAuth in the Security tab in the portal. But it still didn't accept non http(s).
How did you manage to get it work?

Answer (score 5):

You can use whatever you want as your redirect URI. You have to pass the redirect URI as a Get-parameter in your authorize request.

Make sure both of them match! You can navigate to subfolders or add additional parameters to it, but the beginning of it has to stay the same.

I would suggest not to use your website, but to link to one of your apps url schemes.
For a guide on how to set those up, look here: http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

So for example you could use `myapp://` as your default redirect URI, that you want to register with instagram.

Inside your app you can add additional parameters to it. Instagram will pass those on to your redirect URI, so you can read them out again in your AppDelegate or on your Server. Make sure you encode the redirect URI properly. The easiest way to do this would be:

```
NSString *unescaped = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myapp://?someparameter=%@",theparametersvalue];
NSString *redirectURI = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                      NULL,
                                                                      (__bridge CFStringRef) unescaped,
                                                                      NULL,
                                                                      CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"),
                                                                      kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

Now insert `redirectURI` together with your client id into this URL and fire off the request:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=YOURCLIENTID&redirect_uri=YOURREDIRECTURI&response_type=code
```

If you need more than the basic permissions, check out scopes in the documentation.

Comment: You can only register http:// and https:// URIs in the Instagram portal so I don't see how this could work...