# How to solve auth Error "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI" in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, instagram

I am working register a new client from instagram developer page for my iphone app.But I have problem.I created client id but it given this error :

> {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered      redirect URI"}

Actually,I used for connection this link in ios code:

> https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&redirect_uri=igd9fe475655e646cd8025bed7f8626230%3A%2F%2Fauthorize&scope=comments+likes&client_id=d9fe475655e646cd8025bed7f8626230

So,I found sample Client ID.When I've tried to sample Client ID on this link:

> https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?response_type=token&redirect_uri=igfd725621c5e44198a5b8ad3f7a0ffa09%3A%2F%2Fauthorize&scope=comments+likes&client_id=fd725621c5e44198a5b8ad3f7a0ffa09

it's working good on same code.

But when ı created Client ID.It is not working.I checked  [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188786/redirect-uri-doesnot-match-registered-redirect-uri-in-instagram-integration-in).But,I didn't solve this error.

Can someone guide me on how to generate Redirect a new client? or What is the my problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]While registering your app with Instagram(to generate client_id). You have to set the redirect_uri there.

Please check the image and configure as I did.

Comment: I am working iphone project.I am using redirect_uri "  igeb6240d263fb4736b3740af87edd18ea://authorize".while create client_id.I given redirect_uri "https://instagram.com/oauth". But it's still this error:"{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}"

Comment: replace the url : igd9fe475655e646cd8025bed7f8626230://authorize

Comment: I've tried.but it's not working.Now I'm trying like this:      Client ID  e593457f0c634395a8b4c89730ac532b
Client Secret  27a7d51640c9456d8f5d82e76e817ebc
Website URL  https://instagram.com/
Redirect URI  https://instagram.com/oauth

Comment: if your client id is e593457f0c634395a8b4c89730ac532b, you should use ige593457f0c634395a8b4c89730ac532b://authorize instead of instagram.com/oauth. what url you are using in plist?

Comment: I am create URL Schemes and using ige593457f0c634395a8b4c89730ac532b in plist.

Comment: You have to set redirect URI here -> [link](http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/) which should be: ig+Client_id+://authorize (you should replace +Client_id+ with your client_id) and also you should use same client id and redirect uri to the link https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&redirect_uri=igyour_client_id%3A%2F%2Fauthorize&scope=comments+likes&client_id=your_client_id

Comment: I craeted link that:[link](https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&redirect_uri=ige593457f0c634395a8b4c89730ac532b%3A%2F%2Fauthorize&scope=comments+likes&client_id=e593457f0c634395a8b4c89730ac532b) ı found this client_id  [link](https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?response_type=token&redirect_uri=igfd725621c5e44198a5b8ad3f7a0ffa09%3A%2F%2Fauthorize&scope=comments+likes&client_id=fd725621c5e44198a5b8ad3f7a0ffa09) on internet.It's working this client_id "fd725621c5e44198a5b8ad3f7a0ffa09".

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: The problem was OAuth redirect_uri.I defined http://ige593457f0c634395a8b4c89730ac532b://authorize.it is not good.I should use like that "ige593457f0c634395a8b4c89730ac532b://authorize".Again Thank you so much.

Comment: it's possible redirect to the app when the user accept the app? Because You must enter an absolute URI that starts with http:// or https:// into instagram developer

Comment: @Carol did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is having this issue and the redirect uri provided to instagram is exactly the same as the one you're using, i've found that some users were typing my website address as `http://www.example.com/login` when in my instagram api it was `http://example.com/login`.

Then I created a php script to detect if the string `www` exists in my url and then reload to the same page but without the `www`.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www.') !== FALSE) {
    header("Location: ".str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
}
```