# Instagram: Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI

Tags: oauth, instagram

Error

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}
```

Appeared on

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=2fa4359e4340434786e469ab54b9b8c0&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000&scope=likes
```

Instagram settings

```
CLIENT ID   2fa4359e4340434786e469ab54b9b8c0
WEBSITE URL http://localhost:8000/
```

Code

```
$authProvider.oauth2({
  name: 'instagram',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/instagram',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8000',
  clientId: '2fa4359e4340434786e469ab54b9b8c0',
  requiredUrlParams: ['scope'],
  scope: ['likes'],
  scopeDelimiter: '+',
  authorizationEndpoint: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize'
});
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You will need to URL encode the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter to `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000` to prevent that the `scope` parameter becomes a part of the `redirect_uri` value instead of the authorization request.

You'll also have to make sure that the `redirect_uri` matches exactly, including the last slash that you've registered it with.

So then authorization request becomes:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=2fa4359e4340434786e469ab54b9b8c0&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2F&scope=likes
```

Answer (score 0):

When you made a developer account with Instagram you were prompted to enter a redirect URI. The redirect URI you use in your app to authenticate has to match the registered URI.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24669935/1223728)

Basically you need to set your redirect URI in both your app and Instagram to: **ig<CLIENT_ID>://authorize**

In all cases you need to append /authorize or something like that, somehow Instagram doesn't allow just a website without subdomain.