# "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI" - from Instagram in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, redirect, uri, instagram

I am integrating **Instagram** in my iOS app.

My Client id is : **a1eafb31367e435fb541dcfb36d12345**

I have used redirect uri in iOS app as :  **iga1eafb31367e435fb541dcfb36d12345://authorize**

I have set redirect uri in Instagram as: (added *https* as it is compulsory)
**https://iga1eafb31367e435fb541dcfb36d12345://authorize**

My request url is as follows:

https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&redirect_uri=iga1eafb1eafb31367e435fb541dcfb36d12345%3A%2F%2Fauthorize&scope=comments+likes&client_id=a1eafb31367e435fb541dcfb36d12345

But I am getting error as :

**{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}**

I have searched about it but could not find any solution.

What is the issue? Please help me to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try This Link It May Help You http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649152/how-to-solve-auth-error-redirect-uri-does-not-match-registered-redirect-uri-in

Comment: @NSSam thanks for the help. But I have tried it but could not work.

Comment: try it without the `://authorize` Instagram recently changed things in the background which disallowed custom stuff like this. It needs to be a valid url

Comment: @AndyRyan thanks for the comment. Can you please post your answer in detail?

Comment: @Rohan is it working for you

Answer (score 0):

Instagram recently made a requirement that redirect URLs are valid URLs so you need to remove the `://authorise` from the end.

FYI they also rmoved the ability to use custom protocal names e.g `xxxx://redirecturl`

Comment: Sorry I could not got your point. Can you please edit your answer explain it via example using my details?

Comment: Just tell me what to pass in **redirect uri** in ios app and on instagram

Comment: Rohan, did  you understand what is  the cause of the  error?